# SSIS Unicode Characters Not Transferring Properly

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS to transfer Turkish countries from one SQL Server table to another. The records in the source table has unicode Turkish characters. But when I execute my package these characters are shown as non-unicode on my destination table.

I am using locale id as Turkish, db collation as Turkish, and storing the corresponding column in type nvarchar. I also tried derived column, and data transformation components and didn't get a result.

I do not get an error. I just lost the original data because of unicode characters.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the string data types in your data sources and destinations DT_STR (ANSI/non-Unicode) or DT_WSTR (Unicode)?

Comment: I solve the problem by derived column. I cast DT-STR column againt to DT_STR but with code page 1254(Turkish). Now I have a different problem. When I execute package it works fine and transfers unicode characters. But when I deploy the package to SQL server and run with dtexec again I lost the unicode characters. It might be some sql server configuration causing the problem, but I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Below Steps worked for me:

1.right click on Derived Column.
2.click on "Show Advanced editor".

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79md5.png)

3.Go to "Input and Output Properties" tab.

[Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFgFX.png)

4.select the output column for which you are getting the error.

[step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5ZK8.png)

5.Its data type will be "String[DT_STR]".
6.Change that data type to "Unicode String[DT_WSTR]".
7.save and close.

Hope this helps!